# Error when inserting kernel module: module * uses symbol * from namespace *, but does not import it

Tags: linux, kernel, kernel-module

When compiling driver for rtl8189fs, a warning was generated without terminating the compilation:

```
WARNING: module 8189fs uses symbol kernel_read from namespace VFS_internal_I_am_really_a_filesystem_and_am_NOT_a_driver, but does not import it.
```

When inserting this module, this warning is printed to the kernel buffer and the insertion failed.

Driver source: [rtl8189ES_linux](https://github.com/jwrdegoede/rtl8189ES_linux)

Kernel version: 5.4.61

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out that the source uses `kernel_read()` function, which requires importing the VFS namespace outside a file system module. This can be done with adding this declaration before the statement calling to `kernel_read()`:

```
MODULE_IMPORT_NS(VFS_internal_I_am_really_a_filesystem_and_am_NOT_a_driver);
```

This fix should be applied to each file which called to `kernel_read()` in the source tree.